# What is the best practice for merging multiple ids with a single class in css?

Tags: css

I have **3 ids**: `#example1, #example2, #example3` which all share the same css class: `.carousel-container`. At the moment my code is:

```css
#example1 .carousel-container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
}

#example2 .carousel-container{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
}
```

I'm trying to tidy the code so it's like:

```css
#example1, #example2, #example3 {
 .carousel-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
}
}
```

Is this bad practice for browser compatibility? What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Just create a new class with these styles and add that to each of the containers. That way there is no need to reference each individual ID in your css. Much more flexible.

Comment: Your tidied code is an invalid css

Comment: @AlonEitan, maybe he's using a precompiler.

Comment: What would be valid css @AlonEitan?

Comment: @StevenFord `#example1 .carousel-container, #example2 .carousel-container, #example3 .carousel-container { <css goes here> }`

Comment: @StevenFord Look into [sass](https://sass-lang.com/) or [less](http://lesscss.org/) if you want to write a shorthand css like yours (And then compile it into a valid css)

Comment: No, it should work. As far as I know, it's valid CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 3 ids: `#example1`, `#example2`, `#example3` which all share the same css class: `.carousel-container`

Not 100% sure if you mean the element shares the `class` or if you mean the `id` has a child element with the `class` because your `CSS` code tells me you have a child element but the problem sounds like you have the one element sharing the same `id` and `class` so here is the solution for both.

The code below will be targeting the child element of `#example1`

```css
#example1 .carousel-container {...}
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="carousel-container">
  <div class="carousel-container"></div> <!-- The CSS will target this element -->
</div>
```

The code below will target the element with `#example1` with a `class` of `.carousel-container`

```css
#example1.carousel-container {...}
```

```html
<div id="example1" class="carousel-container"> <!-- The CSS will target this element -->
  <div class="carousel-container"></div>
</div>
```

So to target all the elements with an `id` of `#example1`, `#example2`, `#example3` with a child element with the `class` of `.carousel-container`

```css
#example1 .carousel-container,
#example2 .carousel-container,
#example3 .carousel-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

If you want to do something like your "tidy" version you'll have to use a preprocessor like `SASS`/`SCSS` or `LESS`

[More about SASS](https://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: I might have to look into SASS eventually by the sounds of it. I'm very new to developing so I was having trouble explaining the structure but you answered it exactly it perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @StevenFord It's ok happy to help. once you have learnt `CSS` definitely start to learn `SASS`/`SCSS` it adds some useful stuff to `CSS`

Answer (score 1):

The CSS way to do this is like this:

```
#example1 .carousel-container,
#example2 .carousel-container,
#example3 .carousel-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
  /* et cetera */
}
```

Alternatively, you can do as suggested in comments and just make a new class for this purpose and simply reference that class instead:

```
.my-custom-carousel-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
  /* et cetera */
}
```

Or, if `.carousel-container` isn't used with different styles anywhere else, then you don't even need to do either of the above options. You can simply add the styles to that class itself and be done with it:

```
.carousel-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
  /* et cetera */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I think your top option is the best method for what i'm doing as I have multiple section classes that sometimes share styles and sometimes don't.

Answer (score 1):

you can't put a class inside an id style.
what you can do is in your html file where you have the id is add the class with the style:

```
<div id="example1" class="carousel_container"></div>
<div id="example2" class="carousel_container"></div>
<div id="example3" class="carousel_container"></div>
```

then in your css file, you don't have to reference the ids just style the .carousel_container

```
.carousel-container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```